# calling methods defined in .dll C# library

Tags: c#, .net, dll

I'm trying to write a .dll library in C#. This is the code:

```
namespace StreamManager
{

    public class ManageStream
    {

        public static class ThreadSafe
        {
            public static readonly object _locker = new object();
            public static Bitmap _snapshot;

            public static Bitmap Snapshot
            {
                get
                {
                    lock (_locker)
                    {
                        return _snapshot;
                    }
                }
                set
                {
                    lock (_locker)
                    {
                        _snapshot = value;
                    }
                }
            }

        }

        public class CoupleFrames
        {
            public CoupleFrames(ColorImageFrame cif, Bitmap df)
            {
                this.colorFrame = cif;
                this.desktopFrame = df;
            }

            public ColorImageFrame colorFrame;
            public Bitmap desktopFrame;
        }

        public static long Multiply(long x, long y)
        {
            return (x * y);
        }
    }
}
```

But I can't access those methods from another C# application.

I can only navigate through the classes:

`StreamManager.ManageStream.ThreadSafe` and `StreamManager.ManageStream.CoupleFrames`

I can't use the method `Multiply(long x, long y)` or access the member `Snapshot`.

Comment: There doesn't appear to be anything stopping you from calling `StreamManager.ManageStream.Multiply`.. what happens when you try?

Comment: Why can't you?  Do you get an error message?

Comment: Can you post how are you triying to access to those members?

Comment: Sorry for asking, but if you have never created any C# dll, then you might have skipped that.. After creating project#1 with your app and project#2 with your dll, have you "added a reference" in APP that points to the other project?

Comment: I have tried closing and reopening visual studio and all works good. Sorry for the stupid question :\

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any reason why you wouldn't be able to call StreamManager.ManageStream.Multiply at any point as long as you have the reference to the DLL added to your project. Seems to work for me.

I created a new Class Library project, set the following as the code:

```
namespace StreamManager
{
    public class ManageStream
    {
        public static long Multiply(long x, long y)
        {
            return (x * y);
        }
    }
}
```

I then compiled it as a DLL, created a new console app, added the reference to the DLL and was able to call 
StreamManager.ManageStream.Multiply with no issues.